# How do I create Mongoose schema keys from JSON

Tags: json, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to figure out how to define the keys of a Mongoose schema via a JSON file. The code I have right now trying to implement this so far looks like this:

```
const schemaData = require('./myData.json')

const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema();

schemaData.pages.forEach(page => {
    page.forEach(subpages => {
        mySchema.add(subpage.uniqueID : {type: String, default: ''});
    }
};
```

I've seen some examples on how to define a schema via JSON, but I don't seem to see any way to dynamically define the key name for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the keys oj your Json, then add an object with `[key]: { type: 'String', default: '' }`. The code snippet runs an example with a simple object (not a schema).

```js
let schema = {};
let jsonData = {
  foo: 'foo45',
  bar: 'bar',
  toto: 'toto'
}
Object.keys(jsonData).map(function(key) {
  schema[key] = { type: 'String', default: ''}
});
console.log(schema);
```

### Adaptation for mongoose.Schema

```
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({});
const schemaData = require('./myData.json')

// map down to where you need to get your subpages
Object.keys(subpages).map(function(key) {
  mySchema.add({
    [key]: { type: 'String', default: ''}
  });
});
console.log(mySchema.paths);
```

This would give:

```
{ _id: 
   ObjectId {
     path: '_id',
     instance: 'ObjectID',
     validators: [],
     getters: [],
     setters: [ [Function: resetId] ],
     options: { auto: true, type: [Function] },
     _index: null,
     defaultValue: { [Function: defaultId] '$runBeforeSetters': true },
     [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true },
  foo: 
   SchemaString {
     enumValues: [],
     regExp: null,
     path: 'foo',
     instance: 'String',
     validators: [],
     getters: [],
     setters: [],
     options: { type: 'String', default: '' },
     _index: null,
     defaultValue: '',
     [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true },
  bar: 
   SchemaString {
     enumValues: [],
     regExp: null,
     path: 'bar',
     instance: 'String',
     validators: [],
     getters: [],
     setters: [],
     options: { type: 'String', default: '' },
     _index: null,
     defaultValue: '',
     [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true },
  toto: 
   SchemaString {
     enumValues: [],
     regExp: null,
     path: 'toto',
     instance: 'String',
     validators: [],
     getters: [],
     setters: [],
     options: { type: 'String', default: '' },
     _index: null,
     defaultValue: '',
     [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true } }
```

Comment: After looking at your solution, I noticed it was actually a silly syntax error on my end that caused some errors. :)
Still, your solution looks a bit more clean, and as a JavaScript novice, always good for me to learn about the other ways of iterating. Thanks!